# copying fields in access by a macro/button on a form

Tags: ms-access-2007

Good day

ms-access 2007

I have 2 sub-Datasheet's on my form,
One display a list of items.
the other is blank.

Is there a way by placing a button on the form "Copy/Add", it copies the highlighted field to a field in the blank data-sheet.

both field's are of the same type.

Thank you

Comment: In regard to terminology, "subdatasheet" refers to a child datasheet embedded in another datasheet, using reflecting a parent-child relationship, e.g., parent datasheet is the invoice header, subdatasheet is the invoice items. What you seem to be referring to are subforms displayed in datasheet view. @Remou appears to have interpreted your question correctly, but I didn't understand your question until I read his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing is to run an append query. Let us say the button is on the main form, you would need a little code on the lines of:

```
Set db = CurrentDB
strSQL = "INSERT INTO TableB (ID, SomeField) " _
       & "SELECT ID, SomeField FROM TableA WHERE ID = " _
       & Me.[NameOfSubformControl].Form.[NumericIDField]
db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

You will need quotes if the ID field is not numeric.